# How to Redirect Logged-In Users tizen

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I want to redirect logged-in user to a specific page have anyone an idea on how to do that

Comment: Have you checked your GET variables to verify that you're getting what you think it is?

Answer (score 1):

This is the approach I took.

I made a landing page of types. The only the the page does is determine if there is an authentication token for the user saved in the settings (meaning that the user was signed in). If the user is signed in then I take them to an appropriate page using the TAU function change page.

```
 tau.changePage('#pageName');
```

If the user is not logged in then I take them to another page. I don't want the user to ever back their way out to this landing page. So I modified the function that the IDE made to handle the tizenhwkey back key event to look at the ID of the current page and terminate if they are backing out of either the login page or the page that shows if a user were logged in.